# SwiftyJSON Alamofire Cannot invoke responseJSON with an argument list of type ((_,_,_,_))->_)

Tags: swift, post, alamofire, swifty-json

Having constant issues with the following code with SwiftyJSON and Alamofire:

```
extension Bool {
func toString() -> String? {
    switch self {
    case true:
        return "true"
    case false:
        return "false"
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
}
                var _enabled: Bool?
                var _username: String?
                var _email: String?

                // Bit where we set the username, enabled and email

                let _baseUrl = "https://url.com/path"

                var createUserJSON = ["user": ["username": _username!, "email": _email!, "enabled": _enabled!.toString()]]

                request(.POST, _baseUrl + "/users", parameters: createUserJSON, encoding: .JSON)
                    .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
                        // Blah blah do stuff
                }
```

For some reason I get the error Cannot invoke responseJSON with an argument list of type ((*,*,*,*))->_)

This seems to happen quite regularly and I usually just fix it after trial and error and a bit of luck. Nothing I can find on StackOverflow helps

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it, the bool.toString() function needed force unwrapping with an !